# c: opaque data type creation, "invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type"

Tags: c

I'm trying to hide the implementation of my struct. The definitions of the struct are located in `Board.h`:

```
typedef struct Board* BoardP;
typedef const struct Board* ConstBoardP;
```

And i want to allocate memory as needed in `Board.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Board.h"
#define TARGET_LENGTH 5
#define DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE 10

 struct Board*
 newBoard(int r, int c)
{
    struct Board *b = (struct Board*) malloc(sizeof(struct Board));

     char ** array;
     int i;
     array = (char**) malloc( r*sizeof(char*) );
     for (i=0; i<r; i++)
     {
        array[i] = malloc( c*sizeof(char) );
     }
     b->_values = array;
     b->_last_player = 'X';
     b->_size_r = r;
     b->_size_c = c;
    return b;
}
```

But i'm getting the error:

> invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct Board’

[image]

I'm running in circles for hours now and need someone to clear my head of the mess i've created. If i want to dynamically allocate memory to an array inside a struct how can i define the struct beforehand?

Comment: where\how is struct Board defined?

Comment: @UmNyobe no where yet. the problem is - if i define it then i can't hide it's members

Comment: as a side note, please don't post images of code.

Comment: don't cast the result of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: use c++ for data hiding ...

Comment: @Omkant c and c++ are different languages. It is as if you said "switch to java for data hiding."

Comment: @UmNyobe : yeah I know but the same code will run without any modification in C++ and he will be able to do data hiding too

Comment: @Omkant: you can do data hiding in C quite effectively. There's no need for C++ just to get data hiding. Also, not all C code runs unmodified in C++ (ever tried to compile a large C program with a C++ compiler?).

Comment: @Omkant You can't do data hiding in C++. If you use classes, all users of the class must have access to its definition.

Comment: @larsmans : nope never tried for large programs . Yeah there are pitfalls ,

Comment: @melpomene: Very true. Unless you use the Pimpl idiom (and take the runtime penalty), or opaque pointers ;)

Comment: @larsmans The "pimpl idiom" is just C-style data hiding (what this question is about) wrapped in a (transparent) class.

Comment: @melpomene: changed the smiley to a wink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *define* the `Board` structure in `Board.c` first:

```
//Board.c
struct Board {
 ....
};
```

Or somewhere else that is `#include`'d in `Board.c`, anyway, the compiler needs to see its definition to determine its size when using `sizeof()` and to access its members. There's an example in the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C) too.

Comment: but i want to dynamically allocate memory to it and hide it's members

Comment: You still have to define it first.

Comment: @Tom: you can't hide the definition everywhere. The primitives that operate on your `struct` need to know what it looks like.

Comment: @Tom: that's right. A good strategy with opaque types is to define the type in a private header that is included only by implementations of primitives (allocation, deallocation and a few other operations), and a public header containing only the forward declaration and declarations of the primitives.

Comment: Simply put the type definiton in the .c file together with the implementation, and write `typedef struct Board BoardP;` in the public .h file.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to actually do the definition, it has to go *somewhere*, right?

The code in `newBoard` must have access to the exact definition, since it's doing things like:

```
b->_values = array;
```

there has to be declaration saying that the `struct Board` type has a member called `_values`.

Also, please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). And avoid using `sizeof (char)`, it's just a long-winded way of writing `1` (which, of course, you don't need to multiply stuff by that very often).

Comment: did you meant the definition?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `sizeof` on an opaque (incomplete) type.

Since you are using dynamic allocation, you should consider to move the allocation inside the init function of the opaque type, ie:

```
Board* BoardInit (...)
{
  Board* something = malloc(...);

  return something ;
}
```

An alternative is to declare a global constant `extern const size_t sizeof_Board;` in board.h, then define it in board.c as `const size_t sizeof_Board = sizeof(Board)`.

Also, **never ever typedef away pointers**. Opaque types are no exception.